# Why am I able to see data in Azure Document DB if it is encrypted?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

As per this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-encryption-at-rest , data at rest is encrypted in Azure  Cosmos DB ( Azure Document DB). When I use Data Explorer in Azure Portal, to view the collections, I can see the data in plain text. Is the data still encrypted when it is stored and is only de-crypted for the Data Explorer view in azure portal?

Comment: "Data at rest" means the data on the hard drives storing it. Go look up the definition of "data at rest" - I think you misunderstand that.

Comment: Thanks, please forgive if it is naive to ask this but does it mean that it is encrypted while it resides on the hard drive, but the Data explorer tool in Azure portal has in built decryption to display it?

Comment: The portal doesn't know anything about how the data is stored; it just uses the same API calls as any of the drivers (or by your app directly). Encryption/decryption is done transparently by the data engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encryption/decryption process is transparent to the end user. Thus, you never see the encrypted data as the platform handles the encryption/decryption. It is still encrypted at rest (thus what @jaxidian mentioned).